# How to store URL parameters in GET requests in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to capture tracking information from an external domain on my Django site. Clients on external domain load a js snippet:

```
(function() {
  var img = new Image,
      url = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href),
      title = encodeURIComponent(document.title),
      ref = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
  img.src = '%s/track.gif?url=' + url + '&t=' + title + '&ref=' + ref;
})();
```

That creates an image get request back to my server at /track.gif.  How can I get my TrackView to treat the get request as a POST request and input the parameters into my database?

**Additional Info**

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^browse_event$', BrowseEventView.as_view(), name='browse_event'),
    url(r'^cart_event$', CartEventView.as_view(), name='cart_event'),
    url(r'^product_view$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product_view'),
    url(r'^track.gif$', TrackView.as_view(), name='track_view'),
)
```

*models.py*

```
class Track(CommonDateTime, models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    referrer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'track_test'
        verbose_name = 'Tracking pixel test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tracking pixel tests'
```

*forms.py*

```
class TrackForm(forms.Form):
    domain = forms.CharField()
    url_name = forms.CharField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    ip = forms.CharField()
    referrer = forms.CharFeld()
```

*views.py*

```
class TrackView(FormView):
    form_class = TrackForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            track = Track.objects.get(domain = form.cleaned_data['domain'])
            track.url_name = form.cleaned_data['url']
            track.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            track.ip = form.cleaned_data['ip']
            track.referrer = form.cleaned_data['referrer']
            track.save()
        except Track.DoesNotExist:
            track = Track(
                        domain = form.cleaned_data['domain']
                        url_name = form.cleaned_data['url']
                        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                        ip = form.cleaned_data['ip']
                        referrer = form.cleaned_data['referrer']
                      )
            track.save()
        return super(TrackView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need POST request? 
Just implement the GET request using simple get() - class view of function.

You can just use check query request.GET directly, or if you want to use form, you can just instantiate it with the request.GET as the parameter, but IMHO, there is no real reason for this.

You can just do something like this:

```
class TrackView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            track,_ = Track.objects.get_or_create(domain = request.GET['domain'])
            track.url_name = request.GET['url']
            track.title = request.GET['title']
            track.ip = request.GET['ip']
            track.referrer = request.GET['referrer']
            track.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=200) 
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

Comment: I was able to get this working (kind of) - but when I use URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/track.gif?domain=localhost&url_name=localhost&title=localhost-title&ip=1234&referrer=letsrefer
I get Error:
Exception Value: 
'tuple' object has no attribute 'url_name'
Do you know if the 'tuple' object is referring to my model? My view?

Comment: @kenSmith, I don't know. Tuple errors are sometimes causes since you have an extra comma somewhere in your code. Try to debug this: paste the url in the browser, and see the stacktrace (make sure you are in DEBUG mode)